# Reopening the taskbar (explorer.exe) after it has been killed?

Tags: c#, windows-7, cmd, explorer, taskbar

I'm writing a small program to fix compatibility issues with a 16-bit program. This fix is to close explorer.exe, as explorer overrides some of the palettes in the program. Afterwards, we reopen explorer.

When using a .bat file, it works:

```
@ECHO OFF
taskkill /f /IM explorer.exe
EmStraditionX.exe
start /B explorer.exe
```

This method isn't ideal, as it requires extra files to download. For the sakes of simplicity, assume that it is impossible for me to distribute more than the C# compatibility program.

My first thought was to just `Process.Start("explorer.exe")`, but this did not work, and instead just opened the 'Libraries' folder in an explorer window, without making the taskbar visible again.

I then tried to use the same command as the batch file, except like this: `Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C start /B explorer.exe")`, which again did not work.

Does anyone know how I can reopen the taskbar from C#?

Thanks,
Ruirize.

Comment: The answer to your compatibility problems almost certainly is not "kill explorer."  Have you looked in to compatibility shims?  (Perhaps forcing the color scheme back to Aero Basic while the app runs?)

Comment: You say that these latter two approaches didn't work--what happened when you tried them?  Did anything launch at all?  Also, did you look into fiddling with the other variants of `Process.Start` (i.e. the ones that let you specify more advanced options for launching)?

Comment: @josh3736: No joke, this is the fix. We were checking what palettes the program was allocated, and because Windows 7 runs 16-bit applications in a different (I like to assume emulated) environment, it overrides the first one for the taskbar. The moment that we closed explorer, the program took control of the palette again.

Comment: @Reuben: It only opens the 'Libraries' folder. Nothing else. The bat file opens the taskbar as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
Process.Start(Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\..\\explorer.exe");
```

Putting the full path will make it work

Martyn

Answer (score 0):

Do you use also "Run As Administrator" function in compatibility options?

If you do - you will start explorer from another session and you cant see window,that is running in other (administrator) session.

Comment: The compatibility program runs as administrator, as does the batch file.

Comment: So you have the answer. This is the reason you dont see explorer. You need to start it as user that is logged in.

Comment: If you check above, you'll notice that specifying the full path to explorer.exe works. If this changes the user that runs it, then yes you are correct.